# How to mute/unmute sound using pywin32?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, audio, pywin32

My searches lead me to the Pywin32 which should be able to mute/unmute the sound and detect its state (on Windows 10, using Python 3+). I found a way using an AutoHotkey script, but I'm looking for a pythonic way.

More specifically, I'm not interested in playing with the Windows GUI. *Pywin32 works using a Windows DLL*.

so far, I am able to do it by calling an ahk script:

In the python script:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([ahkexe, ahkscript])
```

In the AutoHotkey script:

```
SoundGet, sound_mute, Master, mute
if sound_mute = On ; if the sound is muted
Send {Volume_Mute} ; press the "mute button" to unmute
SoundSet 30 ; set the sound level at 30
```

Comment: You can use `ctypes` to make calls to WIndows dll functions, so you can probably also do the same thing the AutoHotkey script does from Python with it. Either way, you need to find the equivalent calls.

Comment: https://github.com/Paradoxis/Windows-Sound-Manager does exactly what you want.

Comment: @martineau ok for ctypes, but how? (My code already works with AutoHotkey, I edited my question in case it could help)

Comment: @Dschoni that look very interesting, please write an answer I will upvote it

Comment: J. Does: I'm not sure. The AutoHotkey documentation doesn't say what Windows functions being invoked by `SoundSet`. In theory you could read the source code for it and find out. Might be easier to just google `Windows win32 sound` to find out what functions are available (and their documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Windows Sound Manager by paradoxis (https://github.com/Paradoxis/Windows-Sound-Manager).

```
from sound import Sound
Sound.mute()
```

Every call to `Sound.mute()` will toggle mute on or off. Have a look at the `main.py` to see how to use the setter and getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you're also building a GUI, wxPython (and I would believe other GUI frameworks) have access to the windows audio mute "button".